# Slow recursive function. How can I speed it up?

Tags: java, android

Below is a recursive function that does nothing. The real function does some checks that actually can remove some of the recursive calls but it's just an example to simplify the question.

```
public void speedtest2(char[] s) {
    int a, c;
    int l, lmax;
    int arrlength = Array.getLength(s);
    for (a = 0; a < arrlength; a++) {
        if ((a == 0) || (s[a]) != s[a - 1]) {
            if (s[a] == '*') {
                lmax = 26;
            } else {
                lmax = 1;
            };
            for (l = 1; l <= lmax; l++) {
                tot++;
                char[] tmp = new char[arrlength - 1];
                int p = 0;
                for (c = 0; c < arrlength; c++) {
                    if (c != a) {
                        tmp[p++] = s[c];
                    };
                };
                speedtest2(tmp);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Calling speedtest with an array containing "srrieca*" will take up to 5 seconds on my lowly HTC Flyer android tablet. Granted in this extreme example, the function is called 1 274 928 times but still.

I'm pretty sure there is something to do to improve the speed of this example.

Comment: using multiple cores? http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html

Comment: What is the purpose of that function? 3 nested for loops * 1 million recursive calls must be expensive.

Comment: By the way, you don't need `Array.getLength(s)`. That's for when your reference has a compile-time type of `Object` but you know it's actually an array. In your case, `s` has a compile-type type of `char[]`, so you can just do `s.length`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip yshavit

Answer (score 1):

Memory allocation is an expensive operation. Your speed is brought down by that `new` statement. Try to allocate one large block for a working area and stay within that.

Also you're going to trigger the garbage collector quite often, which is an even bigger speed bump.

Comment: He can cut out all new statements by using a 2-dimensional square array at the start,  since his memory use is 'triangular'.

Comment: Jems, dould you expand on this ? Not sure I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the garbage collector overhead by pooling the `tmp` array. Of course after you have checked that this *is* a bottleneck in your case.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility involves reducing the number of recursive calls by having some sort of cache that stores results that can be re-used, instead of recursing. Although in your contrived example, it's not clear what that would be.